# Promoting level

Tags: python

I have a chatango bot with a promote and demote function for levels in order to use certain commands. But once I promote someone It ALSO adds them to the blacklist (level -1) so for example. If I use the promote command and the person is level 0, it will add them to the member list and make Him/her level 1 but since it also adds them to the blacklist itll give them also level -1. And because of that, if I restart the bot and try to promote someone it'll just gets messed up.

Here's the code.

```
        # Command Usage: 'promote <username>, 'promote <username> <rank>
    elif used_prefix and self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_req_min_promote and cmd == "promote" and len(args) > 3:
        whole_body = message.body.split(" ", 3)
        promote_username = whole_body[1].lower()
        promote_username = promote_username.strip()
        cur_rank = self.getRank(promote_username)
        try:
            next_rank = 0
            if "-" in whole_body[2]:
                next_rank = 0 - int(whole_body[2])
            else:
                next_rank = int(whole_body[2])

            user_level = self.getAccess(promote_username)
            if user_level == lvl_config.rank_lvl_botowner:
                next_rank = user_level
            elif user_level != -1:
                next_rank = next_rank
            else:
                if self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_req_blacklist_rem:
                    next_rank = next_rank
                else:
                    next_rank = user_level
        except:
            user_level = 0
            next_rank = 0

            user_level = self.getAccess(promote_username)
            if user_level == lvl_config.rank_lvl_botowner:
                next_rank = user_level
            elif user_level != -1:
                next_rank = user_level + 1
            else:
                if self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_req_blacklist_rem:
                    next_rank = user_level + 1
                else:
                    next_rank = user_level

        if next_rank > len(ranks) - 1 and self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= lvl_config.rank_lvl_botowner and next_rank > self.getAccess(promote_username):
            chat_message("<font color='#%s' face='%s' size='%s'>Sorry <b>%s</b>, I couldn't promote <b>%s</b> as they are already one of my <b>%s (%s)</b>.</font>" % (font_color, font_face, font_size, self.getAlias(user.name), self.getAlias(promote_username), self.getRank(promote_username), self.getAccess(promote_username)), True)
        elif next_rank <= len(ranks) - 1 and next_rank >= 0 and self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) >= self.getAccess(promote_username) + lvl_config.rank_req_modifier_promote and next_rank > self.getAccess(promote_username):
            print("%s,%s" % (str(promote_username).strip(), str(user_level).strip()))
            try:
                users.remove("%s,%s" % (str(promote_username).strip(), str(user_level).strip()))
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            if next_rank != 0:
                users.append("%s,%s" % (str(promote_username).strip(), str(next_rank).strip()))
            try:
                chat_message("<font color='#%s' face='%s' size='%s'><b>%s</b> has been promoted from <b>%s (%s)</b> and is now <b>%s (%s)</b>.</font>" % (font_color, font_face, font_size, self.getAlias(promote_username), cur_rank, user_level, self.getRank(promote_username), self.getAccess(promote_username)), True)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
        elif next_rank == -1 and self.getAccess(user.name.lower()) < lvl_config.rank_req_blacklist_rem and next_rank >= self.getAccess(promote_username):
            chat_message("<font color='#%s' face='%s' size='%s'><b>%s</b> is on the blacklist and cannot be removed by you. Contact a person with level %s or higher access.</font>" % (font_color, font_face, font_size, self.getAlias(promote_username), lvl_config.rank_req_blacklist_rem), True)
        elif next_rank == self.getAccess(promote_username):
            chat_message("<font color='#%s' face='%s' size='%s'><b>%s</b> is already a rank of %s (%s).</font>" % (font_color, font_face, font_size, self.getAlias(promote_username), self.getRank(promote_username), self.getAccess(promote_username)), True)
        # Save all the data now.
        self.savRanks()
    # End Command
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, everything seems fine for me. Thanks for the help!

PS: I'm dutch so sorry for the bad english!

Answer (score 0):

```
whole_body = message.body.split(" ", 3)
```

This splits on individual spaces. If you want to split by words (i.e. any amount of whitespace between words), use:

```
whole_body = message.body.split(None, 3)
```

---

```
    promote_username = whole_body[1].lower()
    promote_username = promote_username.strip()
```

Just write:

```
    promote_username = whole_body[1].lower().strip()
```

---

```
if "-" in whole_body[2]:
    next_rank = 0 - int(whole_body[2])
else:
    next_rank = int(whole_body[2])
```

This might give you a double negative, since `int` can be negative. If `whole_body[2]` is `-50`, for example, then `next_rank = 0 - int(whole_body[2]) = 0 - int("-50") = 0 - -50 = 50` You might want just:

```
next_rank = int(whole_body[2])
```

---

```
next_rank = next_rank
```

This does nothing. Why is it there?

---

Your `try` block is overdoing it. It's throwing away the actual exception. Put fewer statements in the `try` block, and have the `except` part only match certain exceptions (such as `ValueError`).

The only times you should be using a catch-all `except:` is when you need to discard any and all exceptions, or when you just need to do some clean-up before calling `raise` to propagate the exception.

---

Anyway, that's what I can figure out. You might want to look at the `logging` module and put `logging.debug()` calls in various points here to see what steps your code goes through and what values it gets for your various access and ranks.

Comment: I've done what you've told me too, And it didn't work until I replace the     if "-" in whole_body[2]:     with if "+" in whole_body[2]: and It still places the usernames on both lists. I need the command to place the user on the Member list, Not member list and Blacklist :(